# Не могу отформатировать диск

Tags: diskpart

Ситуация следующая:
Было два NVME диска в ноутбуке: на одном было два раздела: сам Линукс + swap; на втором было была Windows + загрузчик
В один прекрасный день комп просто завис намертво, перегрузка не помогало, после этапа загрузки вместо экрана входа лишь чёрный экран. Не долго думая я пробовал откатиться (выдавало ошибку). В итоге я не могу форматнуть диск, на котором стояла Винда. Пишет : The disk is read only. Пробовал все мануалы, грузился с iso Acronis, пытался заново разметить через установщик Винды и Линукса, чтобы заново накатить. Что делать? Умер ли диск? Файлы доступны для чтения

Comment: а `smartctl` что пишет?

Comment: У меня щас нет установленного Линукса, могу ли я скинуть скрин с данными SMART другим способом?

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/B83U9

Comment: Видимо он помер

Comment: ЧТД. Винда вырабатывает SSD быстрее линукса. Спасибо хоть данные даёт прочитать... Не все SSD этим грешат.

Comment: Че ж вы так затянули? надо было поглядывать за ресурсом, процентах на 95% продавать... эх!